# Which (La)TeX IDE(s) have good warning/error analysis

Tags: editors, windows, warnings, ide

We are successfully using LaTeX at our company to create our product documentation. We have a custom document class that works OK and we currently use TeXnicCenter to edit our documentation. "We" are a bunch of Windows C++ developers.

I'm involved in maintaining our doc creation process and would like to improve the situation for all here when errors and warnings appear during PDF generation from our LaTeX files.
We would obviously like to have warning-free "builds" of our documents.

The problem with TeXnicCenter is that <strike>it does not parse the pdflatex output and so it's extremely tedious to manually scroll through pages and pages of output to see where a certain error or warning occurred.</strike> though it *does* parse the output and allow to jump to errors and warnings (via toolbar buttons) in the *result log*, it is not possible to jump to the file position where the error occurred, so it is left to the user to read the warning prelude and conclude where, in which file, the error happened, go there manually and see if he can spot the error.

I have tried TeXmaker and it does a semi decent job at parsing the output but it seems it gets lost as soon as there are errors in addition to warnings.

So long story short what I need is

- IDE/Editor for Windows + MikTeX
- One click generation of PDF
- Resulting in a list/table of warnings and errors and info messages that the developer can click on (as far as possible) to jump to the line where the error occured.

Comment: Isn't this a [big-list] qn?

Comment: @Charles: Maybe. Maybe it's too specific (windows, PDF etc.).

Comment: oops... my answer doesn't make sense... but the texniccenter i'm using parses my pdflatex logs just fine...

Answer (score 8):

I have only used it for about 10 minutes, but the [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) plugin to [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) seems to do a good job of parsing errors and warnings.  Here is a screenshot of its error handling taken from their website:
[image: TeXlipse's error handling.]

Answer (score 8):

Texmaker and TeXstudio, although I've never used either in Windows.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what it's like and why it's good in these editors? Perhaps a screenshot would be good, too.

Answer (score 7):

AUCTeX mode for Emacs can pretty much do all of this, and can display equations, etc., in the .tex file, which can make editing a lot easier.  Typing C-c ` after compilation fails will bring the cursor to the spot of the first error.

http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/

Answer (score 4):

I'm a huge fan of TexNicCenter's log parsing: at the end of the latex run, it totals the number of warnings, errors, bad boxes, etc and displays it. You can then use the next and previous error buttons to jump to the next and previous errors in the log file.

I generally author in emacs + auctex, then compile and debug in texniccenter.

Comment: somehow I missed the author's paragraph about texniccenter, but my version of texniccenter works fine for parsing my pdflatex logs with the next and previous error buttons. Maybe the author just doesn't have that tool pallet in his texniccenter?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the toolbar buttons for jumping to the next error! I had missed them up to now. (Probably because they are somewhat disjoint from the result pane where the errors are displayed.)

Comment: Note, I have since updated the question with your info. How do you solve the problem that you can jump to the errors, but then you don't know where the error is located exactly?

Answer (score 3):

I always found that [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) was pretty good at this. My current editor-of-choice is [TeXworks](http://www.texworks.org/), which currently is not so hot on automated parsing of the log, but the way I work means this is not a big issue for me: I always halt on the first error and jump to the appropriate line number.

Comment: Can you maybe post a link on how to tell pdftex to stop at the first error.

Comment: Another vote for WinEDT.

Answer (score 3):

[Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/), without any doubts. While it is the default LaTeX editor on KDE (a Linux Desktop Environment), according to [this link](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/kile/index.php?title=KileOnWindows) it can also run natively on Windows (installation instructions on that link).

Here is a screenshot from its home page.
As you can see, the errors warnings and bad boxes are shown below very clearly. It has keyboard short-cuts for compilation, even to compile just the environment in which you are working at a moment, with a preview in the same window, and lots of other features since its development began more than eight years ago.

[image: Kile screenshot showing some badboxes and errors from the PDFLaTeX output]

Give it a try, you will not regret it.

PS: of course the warnings and errors are linked to the line where it occurs.