# Find errors and warnings in pdflatex output: highlight terminal output?

Tags: pdftex, terminal-output

I'm using [`cmake`](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeUserUseLATEX) to compile a document. For a clean, built-from-scratch compile, this outputs around 1800 lines in my terminal. The `Document.log` file is just over 1000 lines long. Scrolling back over this output is a little tedious.

Is there a way to highlight bits of the output (such as errors, warnings, etc)? Neither `pdflatex`, `latex` or `bibtex` seem to have a `--color` option or similar mentioned in the `man` pages.

I can't find any references to doing this. Is the correct (or easiest) method to use a parser for the `Document.log` file the way [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/errors-warnings-in-latex-output) does, rather than the terminal output?

Comment: You can look at the `texloganalyser` script that's present in TeX Live (and on CTAN, of course).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this exactly what you need, but with help of `grep` you can do something. Let's say I want to compile my tex file via terminal. `pdflatex Untitled.tex` does the job. However, I can pipe the output of this into grep and use color feature of grep to highlight a word (in this example "pdf")

```
pdflatex Untitled.tex | grep -E --color "pdf|$"
```

The result of this line is something like this:

[image]

You can easily do the same for the log file using following code:

```
grep --color -E "Missing|$" Untitled.log
```

In this case I'm highlighting the word "Missing" and of course you can do this for "error" or any other words:

[image]

What is done here, is simply piping the output (of the log file or pdflatex) to grep, highlighting a key word, and printing mismatched words as well (by the use of "$").

I'm not a cmake guy but if you can pipe it's our put to grep, it probably will work as well.