# How to lint for undefined control sequence?

Tags: errors, editors, vim

So I'm beginning to learn LaTeX and often find myself mistyping control sequences like `\idotsint`. I use editor plugins which call `lacheck` and `chktex` on the document which helps catch some errors, but whenever I mistype a control sequence, neither tool reports any issue. Instead, tools like `pdflatex` are left to realize `\idotqint` doesn't exist.

Is there any way I can get a syntax checker / linter to report if I use an undefined control sequence in my document, preferably so my editor and such can know which line number to point out?

EDIT: I am using vim with the vimtex plugin.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is really an editor issue, so you should say what editor you use to write latex.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the vimtex plugin actually supports opening the quickfix window when the document fails to compile, but using Neovim prevented vimtex from completely working.

See [here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/262) for how get it working with Neovim.

Answer (score 2):

A long comment, not an answer: The problem is: What is the list of "legal" commands?

A command (aka control sequence) may be defined (and the exist) with several methods (`\def`, `\newcommand`, etc.) in the preamble, or in the documental class (`.cls` file), or in  a package (`.sty` file), or a package loaded with another package or the document class, or a child document include with `\input`. Moreover a definition could be aplicable  to all the document, or only to some part. This works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\def\Me{I exist} \Me  }
\end{document}
```

But this produce the undefined control sequence error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\def\Me{I exist} \Me } \Me
\end{document}
```

In summary, it is a hard task for an editor (even for vim) know when a command is defined or not, and therefore the question should not focus in in a syntax checker plugin but in the best plugin to dealing with error messages (but then will be a duplicate  of [Errors/Warnings in LaTeX Output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/errors-warnings-in-latex-output)).