# Why wrong spell can't check in tex file with aspell command?

Tags: spell

My aspell version.

```
aspell --version
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.7-20110707)
```

The simple tex file.

```
cat  /tmp/test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\title{First \LaTeX Document}
\begunn{document} 
\maketitle 
Hello, \LaTeX! 
\end{document}
```

You can see that word `begunn` in the test.tex file  is wrong spell.

Now to check it with aspell command.

```
aspell --lang=en --mode=tex check  /tmp/test.tex
```

Nothing as output for the aspell command,why ?

Comment: `--mode=tex` means that it skips macro names.

Comment: Nothing as output for `aspell --lang=en  check  /tmp/test.tex` too.

Comment: Aspell automatically uses TeX-mode when checking test.tex because of its extension (.tex). If you were to rename the file to test.txt (and remove --mode=tex), then aspell would treat is as a normal text file and complain about 'documentclass', 'LaTeX', 'begunn', and 'maketitle' being misspelt, since none of these are English words.

To force aspell to treat test.tex as a text file you can also use 'aspell --lang=en --mode=none check /tmp/test.tex'.

Comment: This isn't really what aspell should be used for though. A better way to find out that \begunn was misspelt is to just run (pdf)latex, which will produce an error ("! Undefined control sequence. l.3 \begunn")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual for `aspell` is at http://aspell.net/man-html/index.html

Firstly, from http://aspell.net/man-html/Spellchecking-Individual-Files.html#Spellchecking-Individual-Files

> If the mode option is not given, then Aspell will use the extension of
>   the file to determine the current mode. If the extension is .tex, then
>   tex mode will be used, if the extension is .html, .htm, .php, or .sgml
>   it will check the file in sgml mode, otherwise it will use url mode.

http://aspell.net/man-html/Notes-on-Various-Filters-and-Filter-Modes.html#Notes-on-Various-Filters-and-Filter-Modes describes the different filter modes.  These include

```
--mode=none
```

> 4.4.1.1 None Filter Mode
>
> The none mode is exactly what it says. It turns off all filters.

and

```
--mode=tex
```

> 4.4.1.6 TeX/LaTeX Filter
>
> The tex (all lowercase) filter mode skips over TeX commands and
>   parameters and/or options to certain commands.

So running as you do either with `--mode=tex` or without a mode switch will check the parts of the file that are not macro names.  In particular, on your sample file

```
 aspell --lang=en check test.tex 
 aspell --lang=en --mode=tex check test.tex
```

both return no errors, whereas

```
 aspell --lang=en --mode=none check test.tex
```

catches all the macros including valid ones such `documentclass`.

Running LaTeX itself is the quickest way to check validity of names of macro constructions.  On your file `latex test` gives

```
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \begunn
           {document}
?
```

indicating that `\begunn` is not known.

There do exist lint like programs for Latex, see [Is there a program equivalent to lint for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163/15925), which capture some incorrect constructions, but they will not tell you whether a macro name is known to LaTeX for fundamental reasons from the way the system is built up. See [How to lint for undefined control sequence?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300614/15925) for a discussion.