# How to make pdflatex in (MikTeX) write only the error messages to the log file

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex

I've `MikTeX` installation on my Windows 8.1. When I generate a PDF from a tex file using `pdflatex` command it generates lots of content in the corresponding `log file` from which it's hard to read errors (if there are any). I searched online but all the solutions I found ([like this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7204/22810)) pertain to using tool other than MikTeX - and do not work when I try on my machine with MikTex.

If we can't make log file to write only the error message, is there any other way of outputting only the error messages to another file, say, errors.txt

Comment: Do you know https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any ? It makes very nice error logs.

Comment: @samcarter I'm using MikTeX on Microsoft windows platform (Windows 8.1).

Comment: yes, you wrote that. ltx2any seems to work on windows - concluding for example from https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any/issues/60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LaTeX build wrapper [ltx2any](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) may be a solution. It creates (aesthetical very pleasing) summaries of errors and warnings in different file formates, amongst them `pdf` and `markdown`.

From its webpage:

> Aggregates error messages and warnings from all tools into a nicely formatted log (Markdown or [PDF](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1488534/11242606/06ed381a-8e03-11e5-99be-7b1312d59420.png)) with references to source files and original logs.

[image]